# Trying to understand the difference between using docker(Scheduler, Queue, Workers) VS Docker(Airflow)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

Please pardon me IF I ASKED A VERY AMATEUR question but after reading multiple threads, posts, references and etc... I still do not understand the differences.

My current understanding:

1st method)
A traditional docker will compose of 3 dockers:

1. Scheduler that manages the schedule of the job
2. Queue that manages the queue of the multiple jobs
3. Worker that manages the work of each queue

I read from this source: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-scheduler-queue-docker

Docker + Apache Airflow will compose a single docker that does the same as above 3 dockers:
2nd method)

1. Worker(Airflow: since in airflow we can set the scheduler and also the queue)

I watched this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvr_WNzEXBE&t=575s

I first learnt from these two sources and other sources but I am confuse about:

1. Since I can use docker-compose to build all the services, all I need is just 1 docker(2nd method) and then set the scheduler which already in airflow to control the workflow, right? Then it means I do not need to create multiple dockers as the 1st method which separate all tasks into different dockers.
2. If both are different, then what are the differences? I try to find it for days but still could not figure out, I am sorry, I am new to this subject so I am currently still studying about it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are pointing at `multi-node airflow` vs `single node airflow` comparison. A multi-node airflow will provide you  more computing power and higher availability for your Apache Airflow instance. You can run everything (webserver,scheduler and worker) on one machine/docker instance but if you project grows, you can make a cluster and scale your pipeline.

Actually, a  Airflow instance can have number of `Daemons` workers that work together to provide the full functionality of Airflow.

With multiple gunicorn workers you can take and execute more task from the queue , in parallel/concurrently. On a single machine (depending on your usecase/cores of machine) you can define this in {AIRFLOW_HOME}/airflow.cfg (for example `workers=6`)

Now since Daemons don’t are independent of each other, people distribute them on multiple nodes/instances (Docker containers in your case). So, probably, this is what you have seen.

**Update:**

1. **about the tutorial links you shared**

As you asked in the comment section, the youtube tutorial that you have pointed to is also using one docker container where you run every thing, you arent using multi Node there.

For your first link (relating laravel scheduling), I am not sure but it seems like it is also using only one container

2. **how you link multiple nodes of airflow in Multi-node setup**
   As an example, if you use same external Database instance (Mysql,postgres) and all your nodes interact with it, similarly, you have same queue from where they take task (may be external/same RabbitMQ cluster)
3. **What is scheduler for, how to exucute**

Scheduler is the thing that actually schedules the DAGs, for example running the weekly/daily/monthly etc as you have declared. In essense, one has only one
scheduler and there are workers that you need more. But it doesnt mean you cant have, you may have two webservers etc but you need to tackle port difference and share metadata between them.

To run the scheduler, you just need to do `airflow scheduler` and it will start picking Your DAGs and starts executing them once it is running successfully. For the first run it will see `start_date` and for subsequent, it will use `schedule_interval` that you have defined in the DAG to schedule them (thats why it is scheduler)

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation but I am sorry, I got  a little confused with your example. Based on your explanation, 1) multi-node airflow means that build an airflow environment that has multiple dockers(But how can we build that, my current approach based on the tutorial is we can build multiple nodes(dockers; webserver, scheduler, worker), and then linked all these with docker-compose)?  2) I should use multinode airflow since its better for project that grows overtime. I am sorry but do you have some examples, please?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but I really want to know more about dockers and airflow. Is my current tutorial that I followed from youtube is not multinode airflow but a single node airflow>

Comment: Could I confirm again. For example, If I build 2 dockers which is multinodes airflow(main: Webserver+Scheduler, Worker). Main docker, how to execute the scheduler and what is it for actually(this is the part I confused the most because in airflow we can use docker-compose to set the scheduler, so what is the difference?)? Worker would be assigned with the dags(this means all my tasks will be performed in this worker docker). But what about the webserver and scheduler? What is scheduler for? Thank you.

Comment: So all I have to do is just create multiple nodes(workers) with each having its own scheduler? and then when I run the airflow scheduler it will get all these workers(defined with schedules), it will then be queue accordingly,right?

Comment: No, like i said, you will have one scheduler and mulitple worker, you need to use one db and queue for all in order for them to work properly